# Correspond colors' order in the legend with colors' order in a stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below:

```
Target_Category<-c("Adhesion","Cytochrome")
Validated<-c(5,12)
Candidate<-c(10,23)
Exploratory<-c(7,6)
Unknown<-c(9,4)
dataf<-data.frame(Target_Category,Validated,Candidate,Exploratory,Unknown)
```

and I create the stacked barplot below with :

```
library(tidyverse)

d<-dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")
d+scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange","gray48","black","green4"),
                    breaks = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                               "Exploratory", "Unknown"))
```

[image]

The issue is that the color values and the breaks are not corresponded correctly since the correct output should be like green,orange,grey black and the correspondence should be like the image below. The legend names' order is correct but not the color order in the plot.

Even when I use

```
d<-dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  mutate(col=factor(col, levels = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                                    "Exploratory", "Unknown"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")

d+scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange","gray48","black","green4"),
                    breaks = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                               "Exploratory", "Unknown"))
```

the output is not like the expected one in the 2nd image.

[image]

Comment: The variable is automatically converted to a factor. The order of those factor levels would set the order of breaks in the legend, but you overrode it—the breaks show up in the order you wrote them in the scale. If you need to control the order, convert to factor and order however you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As camille explained, you can use factor to control colors' order:

```
    d<-dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  mutate(col=factor(col, levels = c("Unknown", "Exploratory", "Candidate", "Validated"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")

d+scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "gray48", "orange", "green4"),
                    breaks = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                               "Exploratory", "Unknown"))
```

Comment: hmm I can see what you mean but there is not the requested correspondence in  your answer as well.

Comment: Ahh, values should be changed also
`d+scale_fill_manual(values=c("green4","orange","gray48","black"),
                    breaks = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                               "Exploratory", "Unknown"))`
Right?

Comment: well no, green should be first at the legend order but at the bottom of the stacked bar instead of top which is now.

Comment: `d<-dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  mutate(col=factor(col, levels = c("Unknown", "Exploratory", "Candidate", "Validated"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")

d+scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "gray48", "orange", "green4"),
                    breaks = c("Validated", "Candidate",
                               "Exploratory", "Unknown"))`

Comment: well that works

Comment: great, updated code in answer